# Thread Termination issue (C): Last thread not terminating

Tags: c, multithreading, race-condition, termination

Why is my last thread not terminating?

I want to start all the threads at the same time, so I have ten threads that once created are put to sleep. Once all the threads are created, I wake all of them to start processing the data. The threads complete except the last thread, thread #9. Does anyone know why the last thread isn't terminating and joining all the other pthreads?

Output:

```
------------------Theatre Seating----------------

0000 0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 
0010 0011 0012 0013 0014 0015 0016 0017 0018 0019 
0020 0021 0022 0023 0024 0025 0026 0027 0028 0029 
0030 0031 0032 0033 0034 0035 0036 0037 0038 0039 
0040 0041 0042 0043 0044 0045 0046 0047 0048 0049 
0050 0051 0052 0053 0054 0055 0056 0057 0058 0059 
0060 0061 0062 0063 0064 0065 0066 0067 0068 0069 
0070 0071 0072 0073 0074 0075 0076 0077 0078 0079 
0080 0081 0082 0083 0084 0085 0086 0087 0088 0089 
0090 0091 0092 0093 0094 0095 0096 0097 0098 0099 

------------------End of Seating----------------

Enter N value of Customers: 2
Number of Customers: 2
thread #0: seller_type1->st = H
thread #1: seller_type1->st = M
thread #2: seller_type1->st = M
thread #3: seller_type1->st = M
thread #4: seller_type1->st = L
thread #5: seller_type1->st = L
thread #6: seller_type1->st = L
thread #7: seller_type1->st = L
thread #8: seller_type1->st = L
thread #9: seller_type1->st = L
Seller type: H
thread #0: Work done
Seller type: M
Seller type: M
Seller name: M1

Seller type: M
Seller name: M2

Seller type: L
Seller type: L
thread #1: Work done
Seller type: L
Seller name: M3

Seller type: L
Seller type: L
thread #2: Work done
thread #4: Work done
thread #5: Work done
thread #6: Work done
thread #3: Work done
thread #7: Work done
thread #8: Work done
```

Code:

```
 * Created on July 4, 2016, 11:27 AM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
// seller thread to serve one time slice (1 minute)

#include <stdlib.h>

//Global variables
//Number of Customers
int N;
char * theatre[][10] = { 
        {"0000", "0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006", "0007", "0008", "0009"},
        {"0010", "0011", "0012", "0013", "0014", "0015", "0016", "0017", "0018", "0019"},
        {"0020", "0021", "0022", "0023", "0024", "0025", "0026", "0027", "0028", "0029"},
        {"0030", "0031", "0032", "0033", "0034", "0035", "0036", "0037", "0038", "0039"},
        {"0040", "0041", "0042", "0043", "0044", "0045", "0046", "0047", "0048", "0049"},
        {"0050", "0051", "0052", "0053", "0054", "0055", "0056", "0057", "0058", "0059"},
        {"0060", "0061", "0062", "0063", "0064", "0065", "0066", "0067", "0068", "0069"},
        {"0070", "0071", "0072", "0073", "0074", "0075", "0076", "0077", "0078", "0079"},
        {"0080", "0081", "0082", "0083", "0084", "0085", "0086", "0087", "0088", "0089"},
        {"0090", "0091", "0092", "0093", "0094", "0095", "0096", "0097", "0098", "0099"}
};


struct seller_type {
  char st;
  int tid;
  int numid;
  char * name;
};


void fillSeat()
{
    char *c1 = theatre[0][2];
    char *d1 = theatre[0][0];

      //asprintf(&d1, "%c%c%c%d\n",c1[0],c1[1],seller_type1->st,seller_type1->tid);
      printf("D : %s", d1);
}

void *sell(void *arg)
{
  struct seller_type *seller_type1 = arg;
  int i;
  i = 0;
  printf("thread #%d: seller_type1->st = %c\n", seller_type1->tid,
     seller_type1->st);


  // do work
  while (i == 0) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    switch (seller_type1->st) {

    case 'H':
      printf("Seller type: H\n");
      //printf("Seller name: %s\n", seller_type1->name);

      //Begin Selling tickets
      i = 1;
      //set time;

      break;

    case 'M':
      printf("Seller type: M\n");
      printf("Seller name: %s\n", seller_type1->name);

      //Begin Selling tickets
      i = 1;
      //set time;
      break;

    case 'L':
      printf("Seller type: L\n");
      //printf("Seller name: %s\n", seller_type1->name);

      //Begin Selling tickets
      i = 1;
      //set time;
      break;

    }


  }
  printf("thread #%d: Work done\n", seller_type1->tid);
  return NULL;
}

void displayTheatre()
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\n------------------Theatre Seating----------------\n\n");
    for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j<10;j++){
            printf("%s ",theatre[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
     printf("\n------------------End of Seating----------------\n\n");
}

void wakeup_all_seller_threads()
{
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
 pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}

int main()
{
  N = 0;
  int i = 0;
  struct seller_type *seller_type1;
  displayTheatre();
  pthread_t tids[10];
  seller_type1 = calloc(10, sizeof(struct seller_type));

   printf("Enter N value of Customers: ");
   scanf("%d", &N);
   printf("Number of Customers: %d\n", N);

  // All error handling ommitted! Yes, ALL!

  seller_type1[0].st = 'H';
  seller_type1[0].tid = 0;
  seller_type1[0].numid = 0;
  asprintf(&seller_type1[0].name, "%c%d\n",seller_type1[0].st,seller_type1[0].numid);
  pthread_create(&tids[0], NULL, sell, &seller_type1[0]);

  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    seller_type1[i].st = 'M';
    seller_type1[i].tid = i;
    seller_type1[i].numid = i;
    asprintf(&seller_type1[i].name, "%c%d\n",seller_type1[i].st,seller_type1[i].numid);
    pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, sell, &seller_type1[i]);
  }

  for (i = 4; i < 10; i++) {
    seller_type1[i].st = 'L';
    seller_type1[i].tid = i;
    seller_type1[i].numid = i-3;
    asprintf(&seller_type1[i].name, "%c%d\n",seller_type1[i].st,seller_type1[i].numid);
    pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, sell, &seller_type1[i]);
  }

  wakeup_all_seller_threads();
  //puts("All threads Start");

  // wait for all seller threads to exit
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    //printf("Thread %d joined\n", i);
  }
  //puts("All threads joined");

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: if I comment out 
line 168: wakeup_all_seller_threads();  
line 67: pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
line 68:  pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
line 69:  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
 then the threads run fine.

Comment: It's likely that the main thread called `pthread_cond_broadcast` before the last thread called `pthread_cond_wait`.

Comment: Huh... never have used asprintf() before.  Neat - memory allocation for the given string.  Learned something today.

Comment: I think that @user3386109 is correct.  Put some sort of synchronization in place to be sure that the threads are ready for the broadcast - or cheap out and broadcast multiple times until everyone gets the message.

Comment: user3386109, so how do I make the 'pthread_cond_broadcast' execute after the 'pthread_cond_wait'?

Comment: @Jwoozy I'd get rid of the `pthread_cond` altogether. Have `main` lock the mutex. Then create the threads, and unlock the mutex. Have each thread lock and unlock the mutex before doing anything else. That way the threads have to wait till `main` unlocks the mutex before they can start.

Comment: Thank you user3386109, it works now. I'll repost the working code for others.

Answer (score 0):

The threading works now. The pthread_cond was removed, and the main locked the mutex. The threads were created and each locked and unlocked the mutex before doing anything else. Then the main unlocked the mutex to start them all at the same time.

Output:

```
------------------Theatre Seating----------------

0000 0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 
0010 0011 0012 0013 0014 0015 0016 0017 0018 0019 
0020 0021 0022 0023 0024 0025 0026 0027 0028 0029 
0030 0031 0032 0033 0034 0035 0036 0037 0038 0039 
0040 0041 0042 0043 0044 0045 0046 0047 0048 0049 
0050 0051 0052 0053 0054 0055 0056 0057 0058 0059 
0060 0061 0062 0063 0064 0065 0066 0067 0068 0069 
0070 0071 0072 0073 0074 0075 0076 0077 0078 0079 
0080 0081 0082 0083 0084 0085 0086 0087 0088 0089 
0090 0091 0092 0093 0094 0095 0096 0097 0098 0099 

------------------End of Seating----------------

Enter N value of Customers: 3
Number of Customers: 3
thread #0: seller_type1->st = H
thread #1: seller_type1->st = M
thread #2: seller_type1->st = M
thread #3: seller_type1->st = M
thread #4: seller_type1->st = L
thread #5: seller_type1->st = L
thread #6: seller_type1->st = L
thread #7: seller_type1->st = L
thread #8: seller_type1->st = L
thread #9: seller_type1->st = L
Seller type: H
Seller type: M
Seller type: M
Seller type: M
Seller name: H0

Seller type: L
Seller name: M1

Seller type: L
Seller type: L
Seller name: M2

Seller type: L
Seller name: M3

Seller type: L
Seller type: L
thread #0: Work done
Seller name: L1

thread #1: Work done
Seller name: L2

Seller name: L3

thread #2: Work done
Seller name: L4

thread #3: Work done
Seller name: L5

Seller name: L6

thread #4: Work done
thread #5: Work done
thread #6: Work done
thread #7: Work done
thread #8: Work done
thread #9: Work done

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 1s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/* 
 * File:   ticketsellers.c
 * Author: iantheflyinghawaiian
 *
 * Created on July 4, 2016, 11:27 AM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
// seller thread to serve one time slice (1 minute)

#include <stdlib.h>

//Global variables
//Number of Customers
int N;
char * theatre[][10] = { 
        {"0000", "0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006", "0007", "0008", "0009"},
        {"0010", "0011", "0012", "0013", "0014", "0015", "0016", "0017", "0018", "0019"},
        {"0020", "0021", "0022", "0023", "0024", "0025", "0026", "0027", "0028", "0029"},
        {"0030", "0031", "0032", "0033", "0034", "0035", "0036", "0037", "0038", "0039"},
        {"0040", "0041", "0042", "0043", "0044", "0045", "0046", "0047", "0048", "0049"},
        {"0050", "0051", "0052", "0053", "0054", "0055", "0056", "0057", "0058", "0059"},
        {"0060", "0061", "0062", "0063", "0064", "0065", "0066", "0067", "0068", "0069"},
        {"0070", "0071", "0072", "0073", "0074", "0075", "0076", "0077", "0078", "0079"},
        {"0080", "0081", "0082", "0083", "0084", "0085", "0086", "0087", "0088", "0089"},
        {"0090", "0091", "0092", "0093", "0094", "0095", "0096", "0097", "0098", "0099"}
};


struct seller_type {
  char st;
  int tid;
  int numid;
  char * name;
};


void fillSeat()
{
    char *c1 = theatre[0][2];
    char *d1 = theatre[0][0];

      //asprintf(&d1, "%c%c%c%d\n",c1[0],c1[1],seller_type1->st,seller_type1->tid);
      printf("D : %s", d1);
}

void *sell(void *arg)
{
  struct seller_type *seller_type1 = arg;
  int i;
  i = 0;
  printf("thread #%d: seller_type1->st = %c\n", seller_type1->tid,
     seller_type1->st);


  // do work
  while (i == 0) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  //pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    switch (seller_type1->st) {

    case 'H':
      printf("Seller type: H\n");
      printf("Seller name: %s\n", seller_type1->name);

      //Begin Selling tickets
      i = 1;
      //set time;

      break;

    case 'M':
      printf("Seller type: M\n");
      printf("Seller name: %s\n", seller_type1->name);

      //Begin Selling tickets
      i = 1;
      //set time;
      break;

    case 'L':
      printf("Seller type: L\n");
      printf("Seller name: %s\n", seller_type1->name);

      //Begin Selling tickets
      i = 1;
      //set time;
      break;

    }


  }
  printf("thread #%d: Work done\n", seller_type1->tid);
  return NULL;
}

void displayTheatre()
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\n------------------Theatre Seating----------------\n\n");
    for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j<10;j++){
            printf("%s ",theatre[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
     printf("\n------------------End of Seating----------------\n\n");
}

void wakeup_all_seller_threads()
{
 //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
 //pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
 //pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}

void lockup_all_seller_threads()
{
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
 //pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
 //pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
 //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}

int main()
{
  lockup_all_seller_threads();

  N = 0;
  int i = 0;
  struct seller_type *seller_type1;
  displayTheatre();
  pthread_t tids[10];
  seller_type1 = calloc(10, sizeof(struct seller_type));

   printf("Enter N value of Customers: ");
   scanf("%d", &N);
   printf("Number of Customers: %d\n", N);

  // All error handling ommitted! Yes, ALL!

  seller_type1[0].st = 'H';
  seller_type1[0].tid = 0;
  seller_type1[0].numid = 0;
  asprintf(&seller_type1[0].name, "%c%d\n",seller_type1[0].st,seller_type1[0].numid);
  pthread_create(&tids[0], NULL, sell, &seller_type1[0]);

  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    seller_type1[i].st = 'M';
    seller_type1[i].tid = i;
    seller_type1[i].numid = i;
    asprintf(&seller_type1[i].name, "%c%d\n",seller_type1[i].st,seller_type1[i].numid);
    pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, sell, &seller_type1[i]);
  }

  for (i = 4; i < 10; i++) {
    seller_type1[i].st = 'L';
    seller_type1[i].tid = i;
    seller_type1[i].numid = i-3;
    asprintf(&seller_type1[i].name, "%c%d\n",seller_type1[i].st,seller_type1[i].numid);
    pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, sell, &seller_type1[i]);
  }

  wakeup_all_seller_threads();
  //puts("All threads Start");

  // wait for all seller threads to exit
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    //printf("Thread %d joined\n", i);
  }
  //puts("All threads joined");

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```